# How do I return a set of jsonb objects

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have defined a function like so:

```
create or replace function get_those_other_strings(pid int)
returns setof text
language sql
returns null on null input
as $$
    select array_agg(t1.text_column) as val
    from table1 t1
    left join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.value_id
    where t2.other_value_id = pid
$$;
```

It takes an input (an id in a specific table), and returns a set of `text` values from other tables that are related. It works just fine.

Now, I try to create a similar function, with the only difference is that the type of return value is not `text` but `jsonb`:

```
create or replace function get_those_other_jsonbs(pid int)
returns setof jsonb
language sql
returns null on null input
as $$
    select array_agg(t1.jsonb_column) as val
    from table1 t1
    left join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.value_id
    where t2.other_value_id = pid
$$;
```

And suddenly I can't do that. When trying to save this 2nd function, I get `return type mismatch in function declared to return jsonb`.
When the query from the function is run on its own, it works perfectly fine, and returns something like:

```json
[{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2","ke2":"val3"},{"key1":"val3","key2":"val5","key3":"val8"}]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1) `array_agg()` create a Postgres array type not `JSON`. 2) You are probably looking for `json_agg ()` per [Aggregate functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver It works, naturally. And I feel very stupid now.